# How to throw Exception in Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I want my Databricks notebook to fail if a certain condition is satisfied. Right now I am using `dbutils.notebook.exit()` but it does not cause the notebook to fail and I will get mail like notebook run is successful. How can I make my notebook fail?

Comment: You can throw an exception to force the notebook fail as mentioned here https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#run-example

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Correct, although dbutils.notebook.exit("Custom message") makes the job skip rest of the commands, the job is marked as succeeded. We can use raise Exception if its a python notebook. This will also skip the rest of the commands, but mark the job as failed.

```
if condition: 
  raise Exception("Custom message")
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the better way was to re-raise ***the same exception I got*** after handling...
I've added some reporting I need in except: step, but then reraise, so job has status FAIL and logged exception in the last cell result.

Example:

```
try:
    run_my_job()
except Exception as err:
    log_to_some_place(f"{JOB_NAME} has failed, RunID: {mu_run_id}")
    raise
```

Answer (score -2):

I am on the same boat and for sure dbutils.notebook.exit() is not helping in failing a job .There can be better way to get this done , but the below piece of code will make the job fail .

```
status = 'Fail'
if(status=='Fail'):
  10/0
else:
  100/10
```

Comment: I see how this would work but you should not promote this.